# How to install fontspec on linux?

Tags: fontspec

I tried installing the fontspec package with the help of the instructions provided here: http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html where as the font map file as specified in the 4th step didnt seem to be in the package that I downloaded from here : http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec

I was successful in doing all other steps except this map file and lines in my test.latex file:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\newcommand{\myfont}{SegoeUI}
```

when compiled showed this error

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"  
! The font "SegoeUI" cannot be found.
```

Can anybody help me in getting this done? Is there other alternative way to install fontspec package as i need to work with fonts like Arial, Segoe UI ?

Comment: That is a font and has nothing to do with the package, which is nothing more than the font loader. Do you have the font installed on your system?

Comment: Another problem: `test.tex` instead of `test.latex`.

Comment: @Johannes_B How do I Install the font? Can you help me with steps?

Comment: @KanthaGirish Font installation for your system is not on-topic for us: probably one for SuperUser, AskUbuntu or Unix & Linux (depending on the OS you are using).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Segoe fonts installed in your systems font directory run `fc-cache -fv` to update the font cache (if not already done by your system). Then something should work (run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SegoeUI-Regular}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\bfseries\lipsum[2]
\itshape\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I ran 'fc-cache -fv'. Even then it is saying the same thing. How do I install the font from scratch?

Comment: put the files into your font directory: system wide as root into `usr/share/fonts/` or local into `usr/local/share/fonts/`